# How to use an SSH Gateway with Chef's Knife Bootstrap

Tags: ssh, chef, knife

I'm just getting started with Chef and have a few nodes in a private network that I need to first ssh into a gateway node to gain access to. For the moment i'm using purely password based authentication on both the gateway and the destination node.

```
CLIENT>      $ ssh GATEWAY
GATEWAY>     $ ssh DESTINATION
DESTINATION> $
```

When running the command `knife bootstrap destination.node --ssh-gateway="gateway.node"` where *.node is replaced with the full domain of the host. I get prompted for a password but am unable to gain access.

```
Bootstrapping Chef on destination.node
Failed to authenticate %USER% - trying password auth
Enter your password: 
ERROR: Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: %USER%
```

Perhaps i'm not quite understanding the correct usage of the knife gateway options? I have also tried supplying the `--ssh-user` and `--ssh-password` options with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try "yourusername@gateway.node", it will prompt for the password

Looking very briefly at the code in chef I did not see a way to pass in gateway password info. I would set up key-based access between your host and the gateway, anyway, only takes a minute and saves typing.